# How to setRotation() after setRotationX() in cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x

How to setRotation() after setRotationX() in cocos2d-x?

Obviously cannot call setRotation() after calling setRotationX(), as the second call will cancel the first call.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't call setRotation() then? You're not giving enough context for me at least to understand the problem.

Comment: I want a CCNode to rotate around x-axis first, then rotate again. But setRoration() resets m_fRotationX as shown below.
/// rotation setter
void CCNode::setRotation(float newRotation)
{
    m_fRotationX = m_fRotationY = newRotation;
    m_bTransformDirty = m_bInverseDirty = true;
}

Comment: rotate again around which axis? Maybe (sounds like) you can get to the result using rotation x/y/z separately

Answer (score 0):

If you want rotateX and next rotate node

1. create 2 node: for example nodeToRotate and nodeHelper
2. add nodeToRotate to nodeHelper
3. call nodeToRotate->setRotationX()
4. call nodeHelper->setRotation()

In this way you don't need to rotate in every axis separately

Answer (score 0):

```
Sprite->runAction(Sequence::create(RotateBy::create(1.0f, 360),DelayTime::create(1.0),RotateTo::create(1.0f, 10, 360),NULL));

Here, RotateTo::create(1.0f, 10, 360)
In 1.0f is Time(Second),10 is RotationX and 360 is RotationY.
```